# Number of Longest Decreasing subsequences and RSK

Tags: co.combinatorics

It is well known via the RSK-correspondence that the length of the longest decreasing subsequence in a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ is the length of the longest column of the insertion tableau of $\pi$. ( The insertion tableau and the recording tableau produced by this algorithm have the same shape)

[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%25E2%2580%2593Schensted_algorithm)

My question is what else can be gleaned from the RSK correspondence in terms of ,say,

a) the length of the next longest decreasing subsequence in $\pi$ ?

b) the number of longest decreasing subsequences in $\pi$, given the fact that there is exactly one column of maximum length ?

c) can we say more about the above two questions if we knew that $\pi$ was an involution? (If $\pi$ happens to be an involution, then insertion tableau and recording tableau produced are equal)

Comment: You probably know this, but I figure it's worth reminding people that π is an involution if and only if P and Q (the tableaux under RSK) are equal.

Comment: Agreed. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @Vasu-vineet, while you do have a link to a page explaining the Robinson-Schensten-(Knuth) RSK correspondence, you never specifically state the full name of the algorithm.  Others reading this page would be a bit mystified and may not bother clicking through to read the details of concept which establishes a bijective correspondence between elements of the symmetric group $S_n$ and pairs of standard Young tableaux of the same shape. Also, your wikipedia link has malformed characters in it and doesn't work.  Try  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson-Schensted_algorithm

Answer (score 6):

For a version of a), see C. Greene, An extension of Schensted's theorem, *Advances in Mathematics*, 1974.  Note: the result is beautiful, but the statement is a bit delicate.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll take a look at what this offers. Thanks.

Comment: I have typed down Greene's theorem among other properties of RSK here: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/rsk.htm#rowInsertion